# Mysql server under pressure?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, wordpress

I'm having issue with a server than hosting 5 Wordpress and 1 staging
Including on Woocommerce and one Bbpress with huge db.
The server got 120Go Ram with 500Mo swap set.

I have a TTFB around 3s...

And some SQL query make about 2s to get result.
I solved a problem about an index with varchar(191) and table structure varachar(250)
But I didn't get much from this

I have some table with huge index mabe it's an other point to fix.

I think main of my problem is due to MySQL server and SQL request latency.

I already make several optimisation, using many level of cache (redis cache / website cache / DNS cache)

But before switching on other technical point I would like to be sure to get the maximum from MySQL.

Here is `my.cnf` file

```
[mysql]
#performance_schema = on
#max_allowed_packet=4196M
max_connections = 200

[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[mysqld]
query_cache_size=64M
join_buffer_size = 8M

#bind-address = ::
sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
local-infile=0
#max_allowed_packet=4196M
net_buffer_length=16K
wait_timeout=300
interactive_timeout=300

####### Control slow query ######

slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1

####### CACHE - Management - 15/09/23 ######
tmp_table_size = 4096M
max_heap_table_size = 4096M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
thread_cache_size = 16
#temptable_max_mmap = 4G
#temptable_max_ram = 4G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=48G
innodb_log_file_size=6G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 48
performance_schema=ON
table_definition_cache=1500
skip-name-resolve=ON
query_cache_size=8G
#query_cache=0

[client]
#wait_timeout=31536000
#max_allowed_packet=4196M

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=4196M
```

I was wondering if changing these values can help my problem

```
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
max_connections=500
thread_cache_size=50
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=100G
wait_timeout=300
interactive_timeout=300
net_buffer_length=64K
max_allowed_packet=256M
```

Comment: did the changes help your problem?

Comment: Hi,

you mean the second part of values ?

I already made some changes by the past that help me pass from SQL answer of 10s to 3s.

And now I wonder should I update my.cnf with the value that I shown.

Yesterday my Apache got back to 3s answer when there were 340 simultaneous connections, which is nothing.

Comment: And I have a problem with max_connection = 500

mysql: unknown variable 'max_connections=500'

Mariadb 10.3.38

Comment: `max_connections` is in the `[mysqld]` group as its a server variable. Try removing the `query_cache`, it a major scalability bottleneck. Recommend setting [min_examined_row_limit=1000](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#min_examined_row_limit) when using `log_queries_not_using_indexes` otherwise it will be too noisy.  `thread_cache_size` should support the number of connections normally running.